# Comparing two arrays which contain objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I have two arrays which only contain objects for groups. One contains all the groups on my site. The other contains all the groups a specific user belongs to.

I'd like to subtract: `All the groups` - `user groups`  = `groups remaining`

I'm using AngularJS, I'm not sure if that helps here or not (maybe a filter could be used).

I looked at previous questions and came across some options:

These are the ones I tried:

```
$scope.availableGroups =  $($scope.groups).not($scope.assignedGroups).get();
$scope.availableGroups = $.grep($scope.groups,function(x) {return $.inArray(x, $scope.assignedGroups) < 0})
```

This is one of the arrays:

assignedGroups:

```
[{
    id: 115,
    name: 'Test Group 2',
    Description: '',
    owner: 10,
    OwnerIsUser: false,
}, {
    id: 116,
    name: 'Test Group 3',
    Description: '',
    owner: 71,
    OwnerIsUser: false,
}, {
    id: 117,
    name: 'Test Group 4',
    Description: '',
    owner: 71,
    OwnerIsUser: false,
}, {
    id: 118,
    name: 'Test Group 5',
    Description: '',
    owner: 115,
    OwnerIsUser: false,
}, {
    id: 119,
    name: 'Test Group 6',
    Description: '',
    owner: 8,
    OwnerIsUser: true,
}];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should extract ids to an object first and then compare two objects. Eg:

```
var assignedGroupsIds = {};
var groupsIds = {};
var result = [];

$scope.assignedGroups.forEach(function (el, i) {
  assignedGroupsIds[el.id] = $scope.assignedGroups[i];
});

$scope.groups.forEach(function (el, i) {
  groupsIds[el.id] = $scope.groups[i];
});

for (var i in groupsIds) {
    if (!assignedGroupsIds.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        result.push(groupsIds[i]);
    }
}

return result;
```

Here goes simplified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NLQGL/2/
Adjust it to your needs.

I think it's a good solution since you could reuse the `groupsIds` object (it seems not to change often).

Note: Feel free to use `angular.forEach()` instead of `Array.prototype.forEach`

Comment: Hey, I'm still working on this. I think I'm running into a timing issue: I've uploaded my service and added some notes: http://jsfiddle.net/9dz5A/1/

Comment: I think your comment is a completely different issue.
I have no idea what SPServices is and how possibly could I test or debug this.
But I'm pretty sure assignedGroups in your code is undefined. Maybe it's a scoping issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of Angular JS's `$filter` service and Lo-dash's `findWhere` method to get unique objects in two arrays, try this :

```
// When you don't know the lengths of the arrays you want to compare
    var allTheGroupsLength = allTheGroups.length;
    var userGroupsLength = userGroups.length;
    var groupsRemaining = [];

    if(allTheGroupsLength > userGroupsLength){
        getDifference(allTheGroups, userGroups);
    }
    else{
        getDifference(userGroups, allTheGroups);
    }

    function getDifference(obj1, obj2){
        groupsRemaining  = $filter('filter')(obj1, function(obj1Value){
              return !Boolean(_.findWhere(obj2, obj1Value));
        });
    }
```

**OR**

```
//All the groups - user groups = groups remaining

 groupsRemaining  = $filter('filter')(allTheGroups, function(allTheGroupsObj){
                  return !Boolean(_.findWhere(userGroups, allTheGroupsObj));
              });
```

**Using only Angular JS**

```
  groupsRemaining =  $filter('filter')(allTheGroups, function(allTheGroupsObj){
                      return !angular.equals(allTheGroupsObj, $filter('filter')(userGroups, function(userGroupsObj){
                      return angular.equals(allTheGroupsObj,userGroupsObj);})[0]);
                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
// .compare method to Array's prototype to call it on any array
Array.prototype.compare = function (array) 
{
    if (!array)
        return false;

    // compare lengths
    if (this.length != array.length)
        return false;

    for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++)
    {
        if (this[i] instanceof Array && array[i] instanceof Array) 
        {
           if (!this[i].compare(array[i]))
              return false;
        }
        else if (this[i] != array[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Result**

```
[1, 2, [3, 4]].compare([1, 2, [3, 4]]) === true;
[1, 2, 1, 2].compare([1, 2, 1, 2]) === true;
```

**Json Diff**

```
function diff(obj1, obj2)
 {
    var result = {};
    $.each(obj1, function (key, value)
    {
        if (!obj2.hasOwnProperty(key) || obj2[key] !== obj1[key])
        {
            result[key] = value;
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. I'm trying to get a 3rd array that's the difference between 2 array of objects. This solution is just comparing two arrays.

Answer (score -3):

> (maybe a filter could be used).

If you want to filter out all unused groups, a filter is the right decision:

```
var groups=["admin","moderator","reader","writer"]

var user={
   name:"the user",
   groups:["reader", "writer"]
};

console.log(groups.filter(function(group){
    if (user.groups.indexOf(group)==-1) return true;
}));
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UDaUG/).

For the documentation take a loog at MDN [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

For a future solution with `find` or `findIndex` take a look at [this](http://www.2ality.com/2013/12/array-prototype-find.html) fine article.

Edit: For dealing with `Objects` you could easily adapt the filter function and use a custom comparator function instead `indexOf`. Here another [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UDaUG/5/) for that case.

Comment: I added a Fiddle for that case.

Comment: You answer is the only one that actually works. I'm just having a hard time understanding it. I'll take a look at the documentation tomorrow, that might help. Thanks.

Comment: I tried your solution but edited the groups to reflect how my data is modeled. It doesn't work unfortunately. http://jsfiddle.net/UDaUG/6/